# How to not print integer when its value is zero?

Tags: c++, printf

Is there any way to make the following piece of code shorter? Maybe there is a way to use only one `sprintf` command, but I don't know how. I need to avoid printing `x` when its value is zero.

```
char msg[1000];

string s1 = "s1";
string s2 = "s2";
string s3 = "s3";

int x = 0;

if(x == 0)
    sprintf(msg, "%s,%s,%s \n", s1.c_str(), s2.c_str(), s3.c_str());
else
    sprintf(msg, "%s,%s,%s,%d \n", s1.c_str(), s2.c_str(), s3.c_str(), x);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using C++, why not use [`stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) to build your buffer in pieces:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s1 = "s1";
    string s2 = "s2";
    string s3 = "s3";
    int x = 0;

    stringstream ss;
    ss << s1 << "," << s2 << "," << s3;
    if (x != 0)
        ss << "," << x;
    ss << " " << endl;

    // Don't do this!  See link below
    //const char* c = ss.str().c_str();

    string result = ss.str();
    const char* c = result.c_str();

    printf("Result: '%s'\n", c);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

- [Don't let std::stringstream.str().c_str() happen to you](http://blog.sensecodons.com/2013/04/dont-let-stdstringstreamstrcstr-happen.html)

Comment: Since the performance of solution is important for me too, do you know if using `stringstream` is less or more efficient than `sprintf`?

Comment: Performance is always important. The question is, is it *the most important*? I don't know the answer immediately and wouldn't worry about it at the moment. Write your code in a clear, concise fashion, and then work to optimize.  Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Thank you for the effort and the elegant solution!

Comment: Except... it doesn't work. Still figuring out why.

Comment: It needs to be `const char* c`.

Comment: @Meysam Right, but there's something else wrong.

Comment: Hmmm, that's weird, because I can print the result without first using `cout`.

Comment: I'm using g++ on Cygwin...

Comment: That might be the reason. I am using `g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3`

Comment: Weird... I'm trying it now in VS2010, and c_str() returns a ptr to a nul-term. Interestingly, I can see the rest of the string in memory at that address, but the first byte was overwritten.

Comment: Ah.... weird c++ and its lvalues (?). The result of `str()` needs to be assigned to a variable. Otherwise it immediately loses scope, and I'm guessing the destructor writes a null byte to the buffer.

Comment: This is a LOT slower than a single sprintf executing.  You are creating strings, and possibly dynamically allocating in the stringstream.  What is wrong with your solution - it is just as clear as this, and perfectly fine if you care about performance.

Comment: Are you implying that this is a bad practice? `func(ss.str().c_str());` and could cause unexpected behaviors?

Comment: @Meysam Yes, I don't think that is a correct thing to do. I'm not *really* much of a C++ programmer so I'm liable to get little details like that mixed up.  EDIT: [Dont' do `ss.str().c_str()`](http://blog.sensecodons.com/2013/04/dont-let-stdstringstreamstrcstr-happen.html).

Comment: @Michael I agree, I only did this because he mentioned C++. In practice I would do what I described in [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20604004/119527).

Answer (score 1):

Since the printf family of functions evaluate but ignore any unused arguments, this would be one option;

```
sprintf(msg, x == 0 ? "%s,%s,%s \n" : "%s,%s,%s,%d \n", 
          s1.c_str(), s2.c_str(), s3.c_str(), x);
```

For readability and clarity, I would personally keep your current version though. Until really proven to be a problem, readability trumps micro optimization any day.

Comment: There's a branch in both codes.  Yours might not be an optimization.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Yes, that would depend on the compiler, as most non algorithmic optimizations do. A quick test with gcc seems to save some _code size_, not speed, since c_str is only called i 3 places instead of 6, but that's of course not necessarily true.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, break it out into parts:

```
printf("%s,%s,%s", s1.c_str(), s2.c_str(), s3.c_str());   // no newline
if(x != 0)
    printf(",%d", x);
printf(" \n");
```

When trying to do things like this, think of it as a math problem: Factor out what's in common between the two statements and do it regardless of the `if` conditional.

If you want to use `sprintf` (since you changed your question), you'll need to adjust the pointer into the buffer that you pass each time to account for what's already been written.  Also, you should use `snprintf` which takes a length parameter, to make sure you don't over-run your buffer. This length would need adjusted after each step as well.

Comment: @Meysam Do you actually want this `sprintf`'d into a buffer? Or is it going to end up at `stdout`

Comment: I need to pass `msg` to a function that requires `char*` as its parameter.